# Compilar arquivos de vários diretórios distintos em uma única saída

Tags: javascript

Por motivo além do meu controle, eu tenho meus códigos fonte em diretórios separados e não relacionados entre si. Tipo assim:

```
diretorioPai
    foo
        serverSideJS
        clientSideJS
    bar
        serverSideJS
        clientSideJS
```

Configurei o *browserify* (com *watchify*) pra usar múltiplas entradas e ter só uma saída. Meu problema é que o *watchify* só acompanha um diretório - O primeiro na lista de entradas. Ele não detecta alterações no segundo diretório (nem de outros mais que eu adicione). Já verifiquei que nenhum erro é disparado.

Essas são as partes relevantes do meu `gulpfile`:

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
    var dir1 = '/diretorioPai/foo/clientSideJS';
    var dir2 = '/diretorioPai/bar/clientSideJS'

    var opts = {
        entries: [dir1, dir2]
    }
    opts = xtend(opts, watchify.args);

    var bundler = browserify(opts);
    bundler = watchify(bundler);

    bundler.on('update', function (file) {
        gutil.log('Arquivo ' + file + ' alterado.');
        rebundle();
    });

    function rebundle () {
        return bundler
            .bundle()
            .on('error', function (e) {
                gutil.log('Error durante a compilação. : ' + e);
            })
            .on('finish', function (e) {
                gutil.log('Pronto.');
            })
            .pipe(source('app.js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('/diretorioDeSaida/JS'));
    }
    return rebundle();
});
```

Como eu faço para o *browserify*, ou pelo menos o *browserify*, acompanhar arquivos em diretórios diversos e compilar o que encontrar em um arquivo só?